# Inverse Fourier transform of a sine function multiplied with a transfer function

Tags: fourier-transform

I’ve got the following question:

The following relation holds:
$\hat{v}_F(\omega) = \hat{Y}(\omega)\hat{F}(\omega)$

With: $F(t)=\sum_k F_{k}\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k)$

The transformation from frequency to time domain would be:

$v_F(t) = \sum_k F_{k}|\hat{Y}(\omega_k)| \sin(\omega_k t+\angle \hat{Y}(\omega_k) +\phi_k)$

How do you get to that solution?

This is how I got started:

$\hat{v}_F(\omega) = \hat{Y}(\omega)\hat{F}(\omega) \Leftrightarrow v_f(t)= y(t)*f(t)$

so, expressing the convolution:

$\int_0^\infty y(\tau)\sin(\omega_k(t-\tau)+\phi_k)d\tau$

$= \frac{1}{2i}\int y(\tau)[e^{i(\omega_k(t-\tau)+\phi_k}-e^{-i(\omega_k(t-\tau)+\phi_k}] =\frac{1}{2i} e^{i\omega_kt + \phi_k}\int y(\tau)e^{-i\omega_k \tau}d\tau- \frac{1}{2i} e^{-i\omega_kt + \phi_k}\int y(\tau) e^{+i\omega_k \tau}d\tau$

$= \frac{1}{2i} e^{i\omega_kt + \phi_k} \hat{Y}(i\omega) - \frac{1}{2i} e^{-i\omega_kt + \phi_k} \hat{Y}(-i\omega)$

and I do not see how to proceed.

Comment: is your $y(t)$ a real signal ?

Comment: $\hat{Y}(\omega)$ is supposed to be a transfer function

Comment: in terms of a transfer function, then "is the transfer function symmetric ?"

Comment: no, it is not, thanks for your kind elaboration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $F(t)=\sum_k F_{k}\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k)$ so
$$F(w) = \mathcal{F}(F(t)) = \sum_k F_{k} \mathcal{F}[\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k)]$$
Note that
$$\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k) = \cos(\phi_k) \sin (\omega_k t) - \sin(\phi_k)\cos(\omega_k t) $$
which means that
\begin{equation}
\tag{0}
\mathcal{F}[\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k)] = \cos(\phi_k) \mathcal{F}[\sin (\omega_k t)] - \sin(\phi_k)\mathcal{F}[\cos(\omega_k t)]
\end{equation}
You could easily verify (using the definition of Fourier transform) that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[\sin (\omega_k t)] &= j \pi [\delta(\omega + \omega_k) - \delta(\omega - \omega_k)]\\
\mathcal{F}[\cos (\omega_k t)] &=  \pi [\delta(\omega - \omega_k) + \delta(\omega + \omega_k)]
\end{align}
So
$$\mathcal{F}[\sin(\omega_k t - \phi_k)] =R_k(\omega) + j I_k(\omega)$$
where
$$ R_k(\omega) = - \sin(\phi_k)\pi[\delta(\omega - \omega_k) + \delta(\omega + \omega_k)]$$
and
$$ I_k(\omega) = \cos(\phi_k)\pi[\delta(\omega + \omega_k) - \delta(\omega - \omega_k)]$$
So
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\begin{split}
V_F(\omega) &= Y(\omega) F(\omega)\\
&= Y(\omega) \sum_k F_{k}(R_k(\omega) + jI(\omega) )\\
&=  \sum_k F_{k}(Y(\omega)R_k(\omega) + jY(\omega)I(\omega) )
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Notice that
$$Y(\omega)R_k(\omega)=- \sin(\phi_k)\pi[\delta(\omega - \omega_k)Y(\omega) + \delta(\omega + \omega_k)Y(\omega)]$$
$$Y(\omega)I_k(\omega)= \cos(\phi_k)\pi[\delta(\omega + \omega_k)Y(\omega) - \delta(\omega - \omega_k)Y(\omega)]$$
Notice that $\delta(\omega + \omega_k)Y(\omega)= Y(-\omega_k)\delta(\omega + \omega_k)$ and $\delta(\omega -\omega_k)Y(\omega)= Y(\omega_k)\delta(\omega -\omega_k)$ so
$$Y(\omega)R_k(\omega)=- \sin(\phi_k)\pi[Y(\omega_k)\delta(\omega -\omega_k) + Y(-\omega_k)\delta(\omega + \omega_k)]$$
$$Y(\omega)I_k(\omega)= \cos(\phi_k)\pi[Y(-\omega_k)\delta(\omega + \omega_k) - Y(\omega_k)\delta(\omega -\omega_k)]$$
Use exponential representation of your $Y(\omega_k) = \vert Y(\omega_k) \vert \exp(j \theta_k)$ where $\theta_k= \angle Y(\omega_k)$. If $y(t)$ is real, notice the following symmetry and anti-symmetry in frequency domain:
\begin{align}
\vert Y(\omega_k) \vert &= \vert Y(-\omega_k) \vert \\
\theta_k &= - \theta_{-k}
\end{align}
With this in mind, we get
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
Y(\omega)R_k(\omega)=- \sin(\phi_k)\pi \vert Y(\omega_k) \vert[  \exp(j\theta_k)\delta(\omega -\omega_k) + \exp(-j\theta_k)\delta(\omega + \omega_k)]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
Y(\omega)I_k(\omega)= \cos(\phi_k)\pi \vert Y(\omega_k) \vert[\exp(-j\theta_k)\delta(\omega + \omega_k) -\exp(j\theta_k)\delta(\omega -\omega_k)]
\end{equation}
Replacing (2) and (3) in (1) , and factoring common terms, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_F(\omega) &= -\sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi \big[ \sin \phi_k \exp(j\theta_k)+j\cos \phi_k \exp(j\theta_k) \big]\delta(\omega - \omega_k) \\
&+ \sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi \big[- \sin \phi_k \exp(-j\theta_k) + j\cos \phi_k \exp(-j\theta_k) \big]\delta(\omega + \omega_k) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Using Euler's formula gives the terms in brackets as
\begin{equation}
\sin \phi_k \exp(j\theta_k)+j\cos \phi_k \exp(j\theta_k) =  \sin(\phi_k - \theta_k) + j\cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
- \sin \phi_k \exp(-j\theta_k) + j\cos \phi_k \exp(-j\theta_k) =  -\sin(\phi_k - \theta_k) + j\cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)
\end{equation}
Replacing we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_F(\omega) &= -\sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi [\sin(\phi_k - \theta_k) + j\cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)]\delta(\omega - \omega_k) \\
&+ \sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi [-\sin(\phi_k - \theta_k) + j\cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)]\delta(\omega + \omega_k) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Recollecting the real and imaginary terms,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_F(\omega) &= -j \sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi \cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)[\delta(\omega - \omega_k) -\delta(\omega + \omega_k) ]\\
&- \sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \pi \sin(\phi_k - \theta_k)[\delta(\omega - \omega_k) +\delta(\omega + \omega_k) ] \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
That is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_F(\omega) &= -\sum_k F_{k} \vert Y(\omega_k)\vert \Big\lbrace j \pi \cos(\phi_k - \theta_k)[\delta(\omega - \omega_k) -\delta(\omega + \omega_k) ]\\
&+ \pi \sin(\phi_k - \theta_k)[\delta(\omega + \omega_k) +\delta(\omega - \omega_k) ] \Big\rbrace \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Note that the terms in brackets are in the same form of equation (0), hence you can now apply the inverse fourier transform and arrive at your formula.